# PHP Form Dedupe Before Insert

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have the following code that validates that a form has data in it and then i want to make sure that the Name, Email and Address arent already in my database before i insert it...

Can you tell where i am messing up with the below it is throwing the already exists error even when it is unique data

```
    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($_POST['formName'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a name!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formEmail'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter an email!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formAddress'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your Address!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formCity'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your City!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formState'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your State!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formZip'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your Zip!</li>";
    }

    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];
    $varAddress = $_POST['formAddress'];
    $varCity = $_POST['formCity'];
    $varState = $_POST['formState'];
    $varZip = $_POST['formZip'];
    $varDate = $_POST['formDate'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("FormData" ,$db);

        $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE (name = '$varName' AND email = '$varEmail' AND address = '$varAddress')";

        $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

        if($duperaw > 0) {
            echo ("$varName already exists in $varAddress \n");
        } 
        else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO formdata (name, email, address, city, state, zip, submitDate) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($varName) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varEmail) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varAddress) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varCity) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varState) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varZip) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varDate) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);

        header("location: index.php?success=1");
        exit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You're checking to see what's in `$duperaw`; but that's a recordset from the database, and not the actual result of your query. You need to use mysql_num_rows to see how many rows are in that recordset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0` instead of just `$duperaw > 0` to check if your query returned any results.

Also, avoid using `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and are [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for a more detailed explanation. Instead, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which MySQL API to use.

Comment: Wow ok so i need to really catch up on my PHP it has been a long time since i have used PHP. So obviously you were telling me to us mysql_num_rows to fix my issue (Because it did) but also telling me to rewrite my code using PDO or MySQLi correct?

Comment: Indeed. It's always better to have up to date tools.

Comment: Yeah no doubt. I am more a front end guy working in a Java and .Net agency but for a simple project they asked if i could do it in PHP and keep costs down. How long has this been deprecated? But i guess looking back i havent really written much PHP in the last 2 years besides some Wordpress stuff

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), a little less than a year.